# Convert Unity3D json to Javascript Object json format

Tags: javascript, c#, json, unity-game-engine

My whole workflow:

**Unity3D(encoding class data in json format) -> WebGL Build -> Javascript html -> Socket.IO**
Those data type(int, byte[], string) should be readable in socket.io.

This is the function I used in Unity3D, in order to convert a class to json string.

JsonUtility.ToJson();

When I print in node.js, I got this and it couldn't understand the data type.

```
{"Type":0,"Str":"AAA","Byte":[0]}
```

If it's correct, I will get below result when I print in node.js.

```
{ Type: 0, Str: 'AAA', Byte: [ 0 ] }
```

Thus, I need a solution to convert them. 
Could someone please tell me the easiest way to convert them in C#?

UPDATE: more info

Below C# script is working in Unity3D, and I want to convert this:

```
Application.ExternalEval(@"
    if(typeof window.socketIO !== 'undefined')
    {
        window.socketIO.emit('" + e + @"', " + data + @");
    }
");
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Because "Application.ExternalEval" is depreciated in latest Unity, I need to convert them into something like this:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
WebSocketEmitData: function (_e, _data) {
    var e = Pointer_stringify(_e);
    var data = Pointer_stringify(_data);
    if(typeof window.socketIO !== 'undefined')
    {
        window.socketIO.emit(e, data);
    }
}
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your "correct format" is not valid JSON, what you get out of `JsonUtility.ToJson();` is correct. The error is more likely to be in how you handle the JSON on the JavaScript side

Comment: This `{"Type":0,"Str":"AAA","Byte":[0]}` already **is** a correct JSON format ... this `{ Type: 0, Str: 'AAA', Byte: [ 0 ] }` is **not**! Field names in JSON always are wrapped in `"`

Comment: I think I understand better now, just edited my question.

Comment: Before, I used "Application.ExternalEval()" solution and it works well. When I tried to follow the new Unity3D structure, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I use Javascript/Unity/C# heavily on my current project, I strongly advice you to use [JSON.NET For Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347) it will emit a universal json format, that is similar to the one on the javascript JSON class.

Usage pretty similar to unity's primitive json utility.
`JsonUtility.ToJson` => `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`
`JsonUtility.FromJson` => `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`

That being said, let's convert a json string from the C# object to a javascript object.

```
// Convert your json string to a native javascript object.
var jsObject = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(jsObject.Type); // outputs 0
console.log(jsObject.Byte.length); // outputs 1
console.log(jsObject.Str); // outputs AAA

// Convert your native javascript object to another of certain type, 
// will assume the desired javascript type is Player in a namespace Database
var player = Object.assign(new Database.Player(), jsObject);
```

Also instead of `if(typeof window.socketIO !== 'undefined')` use `if(typeof window.socketIO)` it is cleaner, checks for both null and undefined.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested tool. However, I cannot use much 3rd party plugin in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answers myself. I didn't notice that I can emit object instead of string message. and now it works!

```
WebSocketEmitData: function (_e, _data) {
    var e = Pointer_stringify(_e);
    var data = Pointer_stringify(_data);
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if(typeof window.socketIO !== 'undefined')
    {
        window.socketIO.emit(e, obj);
    }
}
```